# Parsing digit which has three letters with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a string which I have to parse digit which has three letters but I want to use same pattern using `preg_match`.

Here is my code can anybody help me out.

```
$string=" AMOUNT - 10.00CAD  0.50XGA  1.00XQA";
if(preg_match('/^\s+AMOUNT\s+\-\s+\d+[.]\d+[A-Z]{3}\s+((?J)(?<amount>\d+[.]\d+)(XGA)?(?J)\s+(?<amount>\d+[.]\d+)(XQA))/',$string,$m))
{
    print_r($m);
}
```

Comment: So, what is wrong with your code?

Comment: hey Wiki it is not parsing the second digit  with <amount> pattern

Comment: 1 capturing group => 1 item in the resulting array. `(?J)` won't help. Add one more group then.

Comment: can you please tell me how

Comment: If you want to get the numbers and letters as separate groups, can you not just use `(\d+\.\d+)([A-Z]{3})`?

Comment: show the expected result to get a quick help

Comment: Array
(
    [0] =>  AMOUNT - 10.00CAD  0.50XGA  1.00XQA
    [1] => 0.50XGA  1.00XQA
    [amount] => 0.50
    [amount] => 1.00
    [2] => 0.50
    [3] => XGA
    [4] => 1.00
    [5] => XQA
) i want result like this

Comment: `[amount] => 0.50 [amount] => 1.00 ` - PHP arrays can't have duplicate keys

Comment: if i want to these two what i have to do

Comment: @sandeeptiwari please edit your question to improve and explain what valid array you expect to create.  All questions should progress in a reasonable time frame to a resolution.  This question seems to be waiting on you to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `preg_match_all` like that:

```
$string=" AMOUNT - 10.00CAD  0.50XGA  1.00XQA";
if(preg_match_all('/^\s+AMOUNT\s+-\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d+\.\d+)[A-Z]{3}\b/', $string, $m)) {
    print_r($m);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.00CAD
            [1] => 0.50XGA
            [2] => 1.00XQA
        )

    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.00
            [1] => 0.50
            [2] => 1.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10.00
            [1] => 0.50
            [2] => 1.00
        )

)
```

Comment: `^\s+AMOUNT\s+-\s+(*SKIP)(*F)|` this part is useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Unless OP wants to match strings that begin with.

Comment: Even in this case, it doesn't do anything. To ensure that several matchs are preceded by something, the only way is a `\G` based pattern.